# How to reference custom attribute from the KDoc of class?

Tags: android, kotlin, attributes, android-custom-view, kdoc

I have a custom View class and in its comment, I want to type something like:

> /**
>   * (...)
>   * When using this view, specify [myView_screenName] in the layout.
>   */

If in the [] parentheses in KDoc is a method, Android Studio automatically links it and you can easily jump there.

**Is it possible to do something similar for custom attribute i.e.: reference it from the KDoc so that the jump leads to corresponding `<declare-styleable>` tag?**
**If so, how?**

Comment: You can try `[R.styleable.View_attribute]`

Comment: @Miha_x64 works better, IDE at least resolves the symbol, thanks for that. But unfortunately, it still doesn't work as "jumpable" reference.